# Code working on vs code but not in leetcode

Tags: python, function

I was solving this problem in leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/regular-expression-matching in vs code, then i submit it on leetcode and the output is not the same

```
def isMatch(self, s, p):
    def main (p):
        for letter in reversed(p):
            if ('*' == letter):
                p = p.replace('*', p[p.find('*')-1])
            if ('.' == letter):
                p = p.replace('.', s[p.find('.')])
        return p
    p = main(p)
    if (p==s):
        return True
    else:
        return False
isMatch(True, 'aa','.*')
```

[code on vs]

[image: 1]

This is the code from visual studio, (runned it from a jupyter notebook on python 3), and the output is true, but when i submit it on leetcode, returns False

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Leetcode runs hundreds or thousands of test cases against your code - that your code works on a specific example doesn’t mean it passes their cases.

Comment: You give the wrong answer for `isMatch('ba', 'ba*')` and `isMatch('ab', '.*')`.

Comment: Its true, but the problem is that in that specific case when i pass those same parameters into the function it returns true. while on leetcode it returns false

Comment: `p.find('*')` returns the index of the first `*` in the string. If there are multiple `*`, this won't always be the same as the index of the current `*` in the loop. So you're replacing a different character than the one you intend.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, ill keep that in mind

Comment: I'm not sure why you're replacing characters in the regexp, though. That's not how regexp matching works.